# Default inheritance_column name in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to change the default inheritance_column for all of my models:

```
# lib/change_sti_column.rb

module ChangeSTIColumn
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      self.inheritance_column = 'runtime_class'
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ChangeSTIColumn)
```

It seems that ActiveRecord::Base does not get it, but subclasses do!

```
1.9.3-p484 :005 > ActiveRecord::Base.inheritance_column
 => "type" 
1.9.3-p484 :005 > SubclassOfAR.inheritance_column
 => "type" 
1.9.3-p484 :009 > SubclassOfAR.send(:include, ChangeSTIColumn).inheritance_column
 => "runtime_class"
```

So how should I correct this to make it work for base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the cause was due to below definition of method ActiveRecord::Base.inheritance_column in Rails 3.2.11 that I was using:

```
def inheritance_column
  if self == Base
    'type' # Note this!
  else
    (@inheritance_column ||= nil) || superclass.inheritance_column
  end
end
```

Digging through Rails commit history I discovered that half a year ago someone had the same issue and commited a [patch](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/839efc5b6d754697682d5b2bd34ef28b2c5d2adf) allowing global override of inheritance column name - hail to open source!

It is included now in both 3.2 and 4.0 branches. Had I upgraded my gems more frequently, I wouldn't have had the trouble.

Another thing that occured to me was that I needlessly patched ActiveRecord with a module, an initializer would have been enough:

```
# config/initializers/default_sti.rb
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:inheritance_column=, 'runtime_class')
```

Answer (score 1):

What about changing it globally:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.inheritance_column = 'runtime_class'
```

Or in each model:

```
class Class
  self.inheritance_column = :runtime_class
  ...
end
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.inheritance_column = 'runtime_class' does not work. And sure, I could easily set it in every class I need, but I just wonder if it's possible to change globally.